# How to use Math.min and Math.max in integer array

Tags: java, arrays, function

I want to find the maximum and minimum values in an integer array but I'm unable to use them .

Eclipse throws this error

> The method min(int, int) in the type Math is not applicable for the 
>        arguments (int[])

Is that I cannot use these inbuilt functions in an array.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    c_21 obj=new c_21();
    int[] a =new int[3];
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=5;
    a[2]=6;
    int max = Math.max(...a);
    int min = Math.min(...a);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your teacher expects you to write an algorithm, using a loop, to do that. Not just to find a method doing it for you. The methods you found, as the message clearly says, and as the javadoc also says, just compare two integers. If your goal is to find methods in the Java library, then you need to read their javadoc.

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 5):

These function expect just two arguments. If you want the minimum of an array you can use IntStream.

```
int[] a = { 1, 5, 6 };
int max = IntStream.of(a).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
int min = IntStream.of(a).min().orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply used in-build java **`Collection`** and **`Arrays`** to sort out this problem. You just need to import them and use it.

Please check below code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class getMinNMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] num = { 2, 11, 55, 99 };

        int min = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(num));
        int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(num));

        System.out.println("Minimum number of array is : " + min);
        System.out.println("Maximum number of array is : " + max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `Math.max()/min()`

   If you really want to use these 2 functions you can do as follows

   ```
   int max = Arrays.stream(a).reduce(Math::max).orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   int min = Arrays.stream(a).reduce(Math::min).orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
   ```

---

2. Built-in function of `IntStream`

   ```
   int max = IntStream.of(a).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
   int min = IntStream.of(a).min().orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
   ```

---

3. Using simple `for loop`

   ```
   int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   for (int element : a) {
       max = Math.max(max, element);
       min = Math.min(min, element);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use `NumberUtils` in Apache Commons Lang - plenty of great utilities there.

```
NumberUtils.max(int[]);
```

In your case:

```
int max = NumberUtils.max(a);
```

Or you can use:

```
int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(1,5,6));
```